# Stata's equivalent codes on python

Tags: python, stata, statsmodels

I am trying to replicate an econ paper using python: The authors use following models (codes). Is there similar codes on `statsmodels` in python or how can I use similar models in python

Stata codes:

```
**First model**

`wls0` *dependent_variable* *independent_variables*, `wvar`(some_variable) `type(abse)` 


**Second Model:**

`reg` *dependent_variable* *independent_variables* [`pweight` = some_variable], `vce`(`cluster` some_variable)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve way will get traction for your question.

Comment: I know nothing about Python but flag that what is distinctive about the `reg` (meaning `regress`) call is the use of survey weights and cluster standard errors. `wls0` is a community-contributed command and I wouldn't bet on anyone wanting to clone it in Python, but the underlying Stata code is not long (in Stata `type  https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/ado/analysis/wls0.ado`) and you don't need all of it.

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349525/clustered-standard-errors-in-statsmodels-with-categorical-variables-python